# Find possible combination of time blocks with incremental start time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

The following code gives me 90 minutes time blocks for a given start time and end time. If we see the first row the 90 minute time block starts from `11/07/2021 04:52` and ends at `11/07/2021 06:22`. However, it can also start from `11/07/2021 04:53` and end at `11/07/2021 06:23`. Also, start from `11/07/2021 04:54` and end at `11/07/2021 06:24`. The maximum value of start time can be difference of end time and the interval (i.e.,  `end - interval`). This also means the end time cannot exceed the value stored in object `end` in the code below, and code below ensures that.

So, how can we increase the start time by 1 minute until it reaches its maximum value?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta
start = datetime(2021,7,11,4,52,0)
end = start + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1198)
interval = timedelta(minutes=90)
ts = [dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') for dt in datetime_range(start, end, interval)]
print(dts)
task = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ST','ET'])
def splitIntoBlocks(dts):
    for i in range(len(dts)-1):
        task.loc[i, ['ST']]=dts[i]
        task.loc[i, ['ET']]=dts[i+1]
        task['alpha'] = (pd.to_datetime(task['ST'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(start, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))/timedelta(minutes=1)
        task['MID'] = 1
splitIntoBlocks(dts)
print(task.head(40))
```

Output

```
['11/07/2021 04:52', '11/07/2021 06:22', '11/07/2021 07:52', '11/07/2021 09:22', '11/07/2021 10:52', '11/07/2021 12:22', '11/07/2021 13:52', '11/07/2021 15:22', '11/07/2021 16:52', '11/07/2021 18:22', '11/07/2021 19:52', '11/07/2021 21:22', '11/07/2021 22:52', '12/07/2021 00:22']

                  ST                ET   alpha  MID
0   11/07/2021 04:52  11/07/2021 06:22     0.0    1
1   11/07/2021 06:22  11/07/2021 07:52    90.0    1
2   11/07/2021 07:52  11/07/2021 09:22   180.0    1
3   11/07/2021 09:22  11/07/2021 10:52   270.0    1
4   11/07/2021 10:52  11/07/2021 12:22   360.0    1
5   11/07/2021 12:22  11/07/2021 13:52   450.0    1
6   11/07/2021 13:52  11/07/2021 15:22   540.0    1
7   11/07/2021 15:22  11/07/2021 16:52   630.0    1
8   11/07/2021 16:52  11/07/2021 18:22   720.0    1
9   11/07/2021 18:22  11/07/2021 19:52   810.0    1
10  11/07/2021 19:52  11/07/2021 21:22   900.0    1
11  11/07/2021 21:22  11/07/2021 22:52   990.0    1
12  11/07/2021 22:52  12/07/2021 00:22  1080.0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you ask does not require your `dts` array at all.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(2021,7,11,4,52,0)
end = start + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1198)
interval = timedelta(minutes=90)
task = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ST','ET'])

def splitIntoBlocks(now):
    for i in range(1198):
        task.loc[i, ['ST']]=now
        task.loc[i, ['ET']]=now + interval
        task['alpha'] = (task['ST'] - start)/timedelta(minutes=1)
        task['MID'] = 1
        now += timedelta(minutes=1)

splitIntoBlocks(start)
print(task.head(40))
```

Output:

```
                     ST                   ET  alpha  MID
0   2021-07-11 04:52:00  2021-07-11 06:22:00    0.0    1
1   2021-07-11 04:53:00  2021-07-11 06:23:00    1.0    1
2   2021-07-11 04:54:00  2021-07-11 06:24:00    2.0    1
3   2021-07-11 04:55:00  2021-07-11 06:25:00    3.0    1
4   2021-07-11 04:56:00  2021-07-11 06:26:00    4.0    1
5   2021-07-11 04:57:00  2021-07-11 06:27:00    5.0    1
6   2021-07-11 04:58:00  2021-07-11 06:28:00    6.0    1
7   2021-07-11 04:59:00  2021-07-11 06:29:00    7.0    1
8   2021-07-11 05:00:00  2021-07-11 06:30:00    8.0    1
9   2021-07-11 05:01:00  2021-07-11 06:31:00    9.0    1
10  2021-07-11 05:02:00  2021-07-11 06:32:00   10.0    1
11  2021-07-11 05:03:00  2021-07-11 06:33:00   11.0    1
12  2021-07-11 05:04:00  2021-07-11 06:34:00   12.0    1
...
```

Comment: Hi. Given the end time stored in 'end' is 12/07/2021 00:50 which is 1198 minutes + start time stored in 'start' which is 11/07/2021 04:52. But ET takes maximum value of 2021-07-12 02:19:00. Where it can only take maximum of 12/07/2021 00:50

Comment: So you make the range 1198-90.